# Posting protobuf message into request body using Alamofire?

Tags: swift, protocol-buffers, alamofire

I've got a serialized protobuf message (in the form of `[UInt8]`) that I need to send in the body of an HTTP POST request.  I'm using Alamofire 3.4.0 and my code looks like this:

```
// serializedMessage is my serialized protobuf message in the form of [UInt8]

let headers = ["Content-Type" : "application/x-protobuf"]

Alamofire.request(.POST, myURL, parameters: [:], encoding: .Custom({
    (convertible, params) in
    let mutableRequest = convertible.URLRequest.copy() as! NSMutableURLRequest
    mutableRequest.HTTPBody = NSData(bytes: serializedMessage)
    return (mutableRequest, nil)
}), headers: headers)
.validate()
.responseString { response in
    print("Response: \(response)")
}
```

The API documentation I'm working from simply says to "write the (binary) serialized protobuf message into the body of the HTTP POST request."  Currently, the server is giving me HTTP/400 (bad request) but I'm not sure why.  I'm still relatively new to iOS/Swift/Alamofire but I've used Alamofire successfully for other GET/POST requests.  However, this is the first time that I've tried to write raw binary into the body of a request so I may be doing it wrong.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Assign the .request() call to a variable, and then pass that to debugPrint to see the 'curl' equivalent of what Alamofire would do.  that might help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: @Gargoyle thanks for the suggestion!  As it turns out, there was a problem with my protobuf message that was causing the HTTP/400.  Once I fixed that, the request worked as expected.  I'm still not sure if this is the "best" way to write raw binary into the body of the request but nevertheless, it's working.